# Signal Queue Problems (I think)

Tags: c, signals

I am very new to using signals and handlers.
My assignment is to create a scheduler program.
When some basic program I made first runs, it sends a signal to the scheduler so that it is added to the scheduler's queue. The program then stops itself and only the scheduler can start/stop it from now on.
I'm using sigqueue with SIGRTMIN because I was told these allow signals to be queued. This is important because the scheduler must give time slices to the programs based on the order that they requested to be added to the scheduler's list.
I think my programs work fine except when I create more than 2 of the basic type programs at once. I'm guessing that too many signals are being sent to the scheduler at the same time and this is causing strange problems (even though the signals are supposed to be queued...)
This is evident because when viewing the programs run, they are running entirely out of order (seemingly random like program 2,3,1,3,2 for example) although the same order repeats every time...

Here is some code from my scheduler program.

```
//setting up sigaction
struct sigaction sigact;
sigemptyset(&sigact.sa_mask);
sigaddset(&sigact.sa_mask, SIGRTMIN);
sigact.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
sigact.sa_sigaction = sigHandler;
sigaction(SIGRTMIN, &sigact, NULL);

//the actual signal handler function
void sigHandler(int sigNum, siginfo_t *info, void *unused)
{
    if (sigNum == SIGRTMIN)
    {
        pid_t nextWorker = info->si_pid;
        insert_pid(&pid_q, nextWorker);
        fprintf(stdout, "PID: %d added to queue.\n", nextWorker);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
}
```

Please help me find out what is happening! :)

Comment: Many functions are _not_ safe to call in a signal handler. Could you perhaps create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that replicates this behavior and show it to us?

Comment: My apologies as I am quite a noob at programming. I'm not sure how to do that, especially with multiple programs interacting with eachother. However, I have uploaded the source code for all my material and it isn't too long: http://www.sourcepod.com/pscizh39-14809 the scheduler
http://www.sourcepod.com/kfbsqs04-14810 the worker
http://www.sourcepod.com/wtnrmi22-14811 bash script

Comment: There are two things you can do to debug this problem: One is to run the scheduler and a worker in debuggers, with breakpoints at suitable places, and simply step through the code to see what happens. The other is to add way more debugging printing. Start the scheduler in one terminal and one worker in another, and see what they output.

Comment: Oh by the way, I see you use `perror` when you don't have enough arguments in the worker. The `perror` function writes out the state of `errno` first, and should only be used when a function documented to change `errno` has failed. You should not use it for general error messages.

Comment: Oh thanks, I've been using it just cause perror is shorter hah..

Comment: If you just want to print to `stdout`, you don't need `fprintf(stdout, ...)`, just normal `printf(...)` works then.

Comment: I dunno how to do debugging in this kind of situation where each program relies on input that changes over time (pids change and such). I've mostly been trying to figure out the problem with your 2nd method of using debug printing with multiple terminals.
The scheduler is supposed to give a timeslice of 3 seconds and each worker outputs 1 char per second.

Comment: In the scheduler, for example, add printing of all variables and return values in the main scheduling loop. Like e.g. after the `remove_pid` call print out the `pid` you got. Also, in the worker you should print the workers pid so you're sure what it is and can compare to the values in the scheduler.

Comment: expected output with 1 worker: AAAAA
expected output with 2 workers: AAABBBAABB
expected output with 3 workers: AAABBBCCCAABBCC
I get the expected output with 1 and 2 workers, but any more and it goes crazy.
Actual output with 3: AAACCCAABBBCCBB
Also, I noticed a problem with the message saying "pid # added to queue". It is always displaying it in the opposite order I send signals. I would expect the first worker pid to be displayed, then the 2nd and so on. However, it is the other way around with the last executed worker's pid displaying first.

Comment: Remember that if there are two or more processes waiting to be run, the OS scheduler might choose whichever of them, and not the one you expect. This seems like a problem where your scheduler clashes with the OS scheduler.

Comment: Ever since I introduced sleep() into my program I went through a 10 hour debugging fight (on my spring break yay) to find out why my program wasn't responding at all. It turns out that the program was actually working the whole time but nothing was ever printed because I had to use fflush(stdout) which I only found out by pure chance. I thought it was a computer problem or something so I reformatted, reinstalled all drivers and all sorts of stuff... so basically using fprintf(stdout, "") along with fflush(stdout) is the only way I could get anything to ever show up.. all because of sleep()...